# Customize the Unidirectional Join Relation JDO

Tags: mapping, jdo, datanucleus

Iam trying to use the Datanucleus API to configure a M:N relation between two tables "which do not know about each other" as follows:

Books:Authors

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Book{
    @Persistent(primaryKey = "true")
    @Column(name = "isbn", allowsNull = "false")
    private int userId;

    private String isbnCode;

    private Str5ing title;

    @Persistent(table="BOOK_AUTHOR")
    @Join(column="isbn")
    @Element(column="authorId")
    Collection<Author> bookAuthors = new HashSet<Author>();
}


@PersistenceCapable
public class Author{
    @Persistent(primaryKey = "true")
    @Column(name = "author_id", allowsNull = "false")
    private int authorId;

    private String firstName;

    private Str5ing lastName;

    @Persistent(table="BOOK_AUTHOR")
    @Join(column="authorId")
    @Element(column="isbn")
    Collection<Book> bookAuthors = new HashSet<Book>();
}
```

Now, as per this link of [JDO's mapping](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/mapping.html#one_many_join_uni), I expect a third table, to be created as the join table, with a new Id column.

What bugs me are two questions:

1. An identity column as mentioned in the link above is NOT getting created.
2. I want to customize the third table to add a little more information. How do I do that? Say, if I want to add a release date or a publisher name, then I need control over the BOOK_AUTHOR table. (Though I am trying to accomplish this task thru the PersistanceAware annotation, I am not sure this is a possibility because the annotation at the table level means that I cannot tinker with any columns in that table, I can only view the information.

How do I get over the problem 2? I can live with problem 1 for a version or two but that needs to be resolved too.

Can the Zens of JDO please help?

Comment: what is "Environment" ?

Comment: Sorry. Corrected it to Author. The description in this code reflects a proprietary functional scenario

Answer (score 1):

Things to fix.

1. You have missed off the `mappedBy` to link the 2 relation fields; you need to add that so then it is bidirectional. If this was supposed to be 2 independent 1-N relations then I don't see how you can share a join table, since data inserted from one side would get out of step with the data from the other side
2. A "join table" cannot have "more information" because your Java model doesn't have "more information". JDO (or JPA) can only map what you model in Java. If you want extra data then you firstly need to put it in your Java model, and that usually means adding an intermediate persistable class containing it. See [this sample](https://github.com/datanucleus/samples-jdo/tree/master/many_to_many_attributed) in their GitHUb.

Not sure what you mean by *"An identity column as mentioned in the link above is NOT getting created."*; You mean the "ADPT_PK_IDX" in the link ? don't think that applies in all cases.

For an M-N relation I would refer to [this link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/mapping.html#many_many_set) as opposed to yours which was 1-N

Comment: To point 2, How can I accomplish this? Are you indicating that I build a @PersistenceCapable class and then add mappings from it to either ends?

Comment: And, about point 1, in what situations does the the ID get generated? I searched thru the docs but could not get it very clearly.

Comment: For 2, yes, they have a sample on their GitHub showing it https://github.com/datanucleus/samples-jdo/tree/master/many_to_many_attributed   For 1. not sure

Comment: I wish this last comment with the link were more prominent!! May I put this in a new answer if you would not mind?

Comment: Link now added to the answer